# Java Payroll Program Error

Tags: java, error-handling, setter, getter

I keep receiving the error message "method getCalcWage in class Payroll cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments; found: int; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

After some research I have tried to trouble shoot my code, but with no success. I have to program for a course I'm taking a Payroll program. I have two classes, one with the getters and setters and the other in the main. Any help would be great!

```
public class Payroll {

    public final int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 7;
    private int [] employeeId = 
                   {5658845, 4520125, 789122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};
    private int [] hours = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
    private double [] payRate = new double [7];
    private double [] wages;

    public void getCalcWages()
    {
        wages = new double [NUM_EMPLOYEES];
        for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
        {
            wages[index] = hours[index] * payRate[index];
        } 
    }


    public int getEmployeeId(int index)
    {
        return employeeId[index];
    }

    public int [] getHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public int getHours(int index)
    {
        return hours[index];
    }

    public double [] getPayRate()
    {
        return payRate;
    }

    public double getPayRate (int index)
    {
        return payRate[index];
    }

    public double getWage (int id)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
        {
            if (id == employeeId[index])
            {
                return wages[id];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public double [] getWages()
    {
        return wages;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int index, int employeeId)
    {
        this.employeeId[index] = employeeId;
    }

    public void setHours(int index, int hours)
    {
        this.hours[index] = hours;
    }

    public void setPayRate(int index, double payRate)
    {
        this.payRate[index] = payRate;
    }

    public void setWages(int index, int wages)
    {
        this.wages[index] = wages;
    }

}


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class PayrollDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int hours;  //hours worked
        double payRate;  //hourly pay rate

        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Create a Payroll object
        Payroll testPayroll = new Payroll();


        //Get hours and pay rate for each employee.
        for (int i = 0; i < testPayroll.NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {
            //Get hours worked 
            System.out.print("Enter the hours worked by employee number " 
            + testPayroll.getEmployeeId(i) + ": "); 
                hours = keyboard.nextInt();


            //Validate hours worked.
            while (hours < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Enter 0 or greater for hours: ");
                hours = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            //Get the hourly pay rate.
            System.out.print("Enter the hourly pay rate for employee number "
           + testPayroll.getEmployeeId(i) + ": ");

            payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

            //Store the data in the payroll object.
            testPayroll.setHours(i, hours);
            testPayroll.setPayRate(i, payRate);
        }
        //Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

        //Display the payroll data for each employee.
        System.out.println("\nPAYROLL DATA");
        System.out.println("==============");
        for (int i = 0; i < testPayroll.NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee ID: " + testPayroll.getEmployeeId(i));
            System.out.println("Gross pay: $ " +
                   dollar.format(testPayroll.getCalcWages(i)) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear - your `getCalcWages` doesn't take any arguments but you are trying to call it with an argument `i` (in the `for` loop)

Comment: Please forgive me as I am a new student. What exactly does that mean? I tried putting something inside the () after getCalcWages but then I get a new error of identifier expected.

Comment: `testPayroll.getCalcWages(i)` can only be `testPayroll.getCalcWages()` - that method doesn't take any arguments. Or maybe you wanted to call `testPayroll.getWage(i)` - that's something you have to know

Comment: @NicoleSweeney Do you use an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans?

Comment: @reporter I use blue j

Comment: I utilized @UnholySheep 's suggestion and put testPayroll.getWage(i) and the program now complies :) Thank you @UnholySheep! My current problem is that no matter what value the user enters for the gross pay, the results displays -1.

Comment: Looking over the code again I guess you want to do `testPayroll.getWage(testPayroll.getEmployeeId(i))` instead of `testPayroll.getWage(i)`

Comment: Now I get the following results... any thoughts?

Comment: Enter the hours worked by employee number 5658845: 1
Enter the hourly pay rate for employee number 5658845: 10
==============
Employee ID: 5658845
Gross pay: $ 5,658,845.00

Comment: @NinaSweeney No question that BlueJ is quite good for training. But the other mentioned IDE's shows compilers errors. Eclipse and NetBeans are free to use. Btw. according Wikipedia, BlueJ projects are easily convert to NetBeans projects, and vice versa. So you can use the advantages of both IDEs (BlueJ to learn and NetBeans to check for compiler erros and debugging code). It is just a suggestion, not more and not less ;-)

Comment: @reporter thank you for the information, I will starting doing that in the future!